# Hibernate map nested object on columns of parent's object table

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

I have two objects in my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Project extends BaseData{
    ...
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
    ...
}
```

.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentMethod {
    private Boolean requestRequired;
    private Integer timeLimit;
}
```

What I want to do is to map `requestRequred` and `timeLimit` fields on columns of `project` table so there is no need to create one more table to store `PaymentMethod` objects in.

Is it possible in general and is it a common practice to do this? It seems a little bit counterintuitive for me and difficult to maintain. But on the other side a lot of tables lead to performance issues as far as I know.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're looking for `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`.  You can find many questions (and answers) about them here and elsewhere.  For example, [When to use @Embedded and @Embeddable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35174981/2402272), [Why do we use @Embeddable In Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19341838/2402272), and [What is difference between @Entity and @embeddable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143707/2402272).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Oh, thanks, it is exactly what I need. Post it as a answer please, so I can accept it.